# Swift Task closure with multiple statements

Tags: swift

I'm encountering an issue with a Swift Task closure that contains multiple statements. I'm trying to return a value from the closure based on certain conditions, but the compiler is giving me an error: "Cannot infer return type for closure with multiple statements; add explicit type to disambiguate."

```
Task {
    try await viewModel.signIn()
    if viewModel.hasError {
        return .failed(viewModel.errorMessage)
    } else {
        return .success
    }
}
```

In the code above, I want to return different cases of an enum (failed or success) based on the outcome of the signIn method and the hasError property of the viewModel. However, I'm not sure how to explicitly specify the return type for this closure.

I would appreciate any guidance on how to properly specify the return type for this closure or any alternative approaches to solve this issue.

Thank you in advance for your help!

**EDIT:**

I tried telling the compiler that my closure does not take any parameters and returns a value of type TaskStatus by doing the following:

```
VStack {
    ProgressButtonView {
        Text("Test")
    } action: {
        Task { () -> TaskStatus in
            try await viewModel.signIn() 
            if viewModel.hasError {
                return .failed(viewModel.errorMessage)
            } else {
                return .success 
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

And now I'm getting an error that says: Cannot convert value of type 'Task<TaskStatus, any Error>' to closure result type 'TaskStatus'.

Here is my enum and a custom button struct that uses the enum:

```
enum TaskStatus: Equatable {
    case success
    case idle
    case failed(String)   
} 

struct ProgressButtonView<ButtonContent: View>: View {
    var buttonTint = Color.theme.purple
    var content: () -> ButtonContent
    var action: () async -> TaskStatus

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            Task {
                let taskStatus = await action()
                switch taskStatus {
                case .success:
                    isFailed = false
                case .idle:
                    isFailed = false
                case .failed(let string):
                    isFailed = true
                    // ...
                } 
            }
        } label: {
            content()
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume your different values are different enum cases?

Something like this:

```
enum MyResult {
    case failed(String)
    case success
}
```

If that's true, you could add an explicit declaration to your Task:

```
Task { () -> MyResult
    try await viewModel.signIn()
    if viewModel.hasError {
        return .failed(viewModel.errorMessage)
    } else {
        return .success
    }
}
```

### Edit:

That tells the compiler that your closure does not take any parameters, and returns a value of type `MyResult` (Obviously you'd use your enum type rather than my made-up type.)

Comment: I'm getting an error that says: Cannot convert value of type 'Task<TaskStatus, any Error>' to closure result type 'TaskStatus'. I've edited my question above and I posted my enum.